# How to use VIM color scheme on terminal?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vim, terminal, color-scheme

I downloaded and started using the following VIM color scheme [Seoul256](https://github.com/junegunn/seoul256.vim). I am wondering if I can apply the same color scheme to my terminal as well? If yes how to use the .vim file for the terminal?

Comment: Are you trying to use seoul256 as the color scheme for gnome terminal?

Answer (score 3):

This isn’t necessarily vim related, and you won’t be able to use a vim scheme directly (unless you do some business like [Conque](https://github.com/vim-scripts/Conque-Shell)). Sounds like you just want to take an existing 256-color scheme and make your terminal use it. There are some built-in schemes in various terminals, like `konsole` and `gnome-terminal`. For extending those options, see [this for gnome](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-terminal/stable/app-colors.html.en) and [this for konsole](https://github.com/nareshv/kde-konsole-colorschemes).

Going to 256 colors is worthwhile, IMO. It's useful for tools like `less`, `git/tig`, `ls/tree` (dircolors tools), `htop`, and many more.

I personally prefer URxvt as a terminal for its support for unicode, bitmap fonts, and colors, as well as speed. You can pretty easily create your own color scheme, and you could mimic “Seoul256” if you like. Here are several [Xcolors examples](https://github.com/trapd00r/configs/tree/master/Xcolors). I find “Nancy” to be an extensive one to build from. These will usually be going into your [`~/.Xresources` file](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/X_resources).

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to enable color scheme on an already existing file, you could try the below syntax in "non-insert" mode.

```
:syntax on
```

If you have a .vimrc file in your home directory, you could make the necessary changes there are well.

http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Change_the_color_scheme

Answer (score -2):

http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Using_GUI_color_settings_in_a_terminal

Mr Google found this; I haven't tested it so best wishes.

Comment: AFAICT this isn't what he's asking for. Also seoul256 is already a 256 color scheme and not a gui one.